# Подскажите как в этой задаче найти в каких строках и столбах находится наименьшее значение

Tags: массивы, pascal

```
program programa;

var
  a: array[0..50, 0..50] of integer;
  i, j, n, m, min: integer;

begin
  writeln('Программа для определения индексов минимального элемента заданного массива');
  Randomize;
  write('Введите количество строк ');
  readln(n);
  write('Введите количество столбов ');
  readln(m);
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    writeln;
    for j := 1 to m do
    begin
      a[i, j] := random(51);
      write(a[i, j]: 5);
    end;
  end;
  writeln;
  min := a[1, 1];
  for i := 1 to m do
    for j := 1 to n do
      if a[i, j] < min then
        min := a[i, j];
  writeln('минимальный элемент массива =', min);
end.
```

Comment: Просто когда находите элемент, который меньше предыдущего минимума - записываете в какие нибудь переменные значения i и j на этот момент. А потом выводите i + 1 и  j + 1 (так как индекс будет на 1 меньше места в массиве)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В блоке нахождения минимума надо запомнить столбец и колонку

```
  if a[i, j] < min then
    begin
      min := a[i, j];

      col := i;
      row := j; 
    end;
```

Ничего прибавлять к индексам не надо, так как вы массив инициализируете с **1**.

```
  for i := 1 to n do
  ...
    for j := 1 to m do
```

Лучше исправьте описание массива на

```
  a: array[1..50, 1..50] of integer;
```

Comment: Спасибо Огромное!